# RAML global query parameters except for a few routes

Tags: raml

I designed my API to accept a access_token query parameter except on a few endpoints such as `/login`. Is there a way to write a RAML rule like this?

```
/login:
  description: hello world
    post:
/hello:
  description: hello world
  get:
    queryParameters: 
      access_token: 
/world:
  description: hello world
  get:
    queryParameters: 
      access_token:
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use trait for this. Example

```
traits:
  - withAccessToken:
    queryParameters:
      access_token:
/login:
  description: hello world
    post:
/hello:
  description: hello world
  get:
    is: [withAccessToken]
/world:
  description: hello world
  get:
    is: [withAccessToken]
```

But using query for access_token is not security. Better use headers for this.